# Android JNI - how to import function from shared object

Tags: android, java-native-interface, reverse-engineering, shared-objects

**Please Excuse my absolute lack of Android JNI**

I want to analize/call one function hidden in shared object: **libEncodeAndDecodeUtils.so**

orginal code uses it like this:

```
package com.midea.msmartsdk.common.utils;    

public class EncodeAndDecodeUtils {
   public native String esha(String str, String str2, String str3);
}
```

Ida decompiler shows:

**Java_com_midea_msmartsdk_common_utils_EncodeAndDecodeUtils_esha**

### *How can I call this function in my project?*

My current attempt:

1. new AndroidStudio project with JNI support
2. adding folder \src\main\jniLibs\armeabi-v7a
3. copy libEncodeAndDecodeUtils.so to armeabi-v7a
4. buid.bradle **android{ defaultConfig { ndk {abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"} }**
5. and creating class

---

```
package com.midea.msmartsdk.common.utils.so_test4;

public class EncodeAndDecodeUtils {
   static {
      System.loadLibrary("EncodeAndDecodeUtils");
    }
    public native String esha(String str, String str2, String str3);
}
```

---

this lead me to error:

> ```
> E/zygote: No implementation found for 
> java.lang.String com.midea.msmartsdk.common.utils.so_test4.EncodeAndDecodeUtils.esha
> (java.lang.String,
>  java.lang.String,
>  java.lang.String) 
> (tried 
> Java_com_midea_msmartsdk_common_utils_so_1test4_EncodeAndDecodeUtils_esha
>  and Java_com_midea_msmartsdk_common_utils_so_1test4_EncodeAndDecodeUtils_esha__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2)
> ```

is this my problem?

> Java_com_midea_msmartsdk_common_utils_EncodeAndDecodeUtils_esha
>   !=
>   Java_com_midea_msmartsdk_common_utils_so_1test4_EncodeAndDecodeUtils_esha

Comment: I had a similar question a few days ago.. I hope my thread can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51613950/kotlin-ndk-and-c-interactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to access `esha` from your own code, then you **HAVE TO** declare this method exactly the same as its original form, because JNI will try to find the implementation following some fixed convention. According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/design.html

> Resolving Native Method Names
>
> Dynamic linkers resolve entries based on their names. A native method name is concatenated from the following components:
>
> - the prefix Java_
> - a mangled fully-qualified class name
> - an underscore (“_”) separator
> - a mangled method name for overloaded native methods,
> - two underscores (“__”) followed by the mangled argument signature

Simply speaking, it will be something like `Java_packagename_ClassName_methodsignature`.

For example, in your case, it is `Java_com_midea_msmartsdk_common_utils_EncodeAndDecodeUtils_esha`.

So, try to remove `so_test4` from your package name.