# Android Studio JNI: cannot compile JPEG c-library

Tags: android, c++, c, java-native-interface, jpeg

My program needs to read jpeg-images from a file native. For that purpose I downloaded official jpeglib c-source code and that works flawlessly on a Windows version of this program, which is programmed using Embarcadero RAD Studio 8.

But when I try to use the same source code in Android Studio JNI, I see lots of errors almost every c-source file :( Below is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, there's errors on both

-Macro expansions (ERREXIT, red underlines), which complain "class 'blahblah' doesn't have a field 'blahblah'".

-member methods (red text in code), which complain also "class 'blahblah' doesn't have a field 'blahblah'".

Looks like there are many C-language classes and fields, or probably all, which are not working. But the jpeglib source definitely contains them all, something is just not working in Android Studio! Probably Android Studio C-compiler is somehow limited, but there must be some way to bypass it...

This problem doesn't exist in C++ source files. I have different source folders for java and C++ source files (and there are also separate jni folder, but I don't use it, probably I should), but C source files resides inside the C++ folder. I have added all c, cpp, h and hpp source files inside the parentheses of the CMakeLists.txt's add_library() directive, but that's all. I don't know is it enough...

I'm glad to get any suggestions how to fix this.

Comment: What is the first error message? Are all header files found?

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Images of your IDE are pretty useless. Post error messages from your build logs. Post the code if necessary. You're probably just missing a path or two in an `includes` environment variable or build  configuration file.

Comment: @thejonny when I click rebuild project the first error listed is "field has incomplete type 'xPen'" and it is from cpp file. The compiler stops building before going to the c-files. All header files are found but I will recheck between h and hpp files. I suppose I don't need to list header files which have same name than c or cpp files in CMakeLists. jwdonahue thank you for your support but I think my question is best I can write.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I hope the following thread would help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51613950/kotlin-ndk-and-c-interactions

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to add all **libjpeg** files to your `add_library()`. The library expects to be configured for the specific toolchain, see e.g. this [example](https://github.com/LuaDist/libjpeg/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt).

I prefer an optimized version of the library, called [**libjpeg-turbo**](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo). On GitHub you can find step-by-step instructions how the library can be cross-compiled for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there seems to be happy ending...

I have to admit that Android Studio most likely can compile JPEG c-library:) The problem "class 'blahblah' doesn't have a field 'blahblah'" was because the library needs to be configured for the specific toolchain, like @Alex Cohn said. But the configuration doesn't happen in CMakeLists.txt, instead you need to rewrite the code itself at some extent. For example, you need to change

-INT32 to int32_t

-#define boolean bool

-#define EXTERN extern

-add lots of #include <> and #include ""

-and more...

If you need to do that, start from header files: don't touch C files until you have headers error free. As a side note, I had exactly the same build order in Android Studio than I had in Embarcadero Studio, but that didn't helped to succeed... I don't know yet, will this modified library work, but at least I think I will get rid of compilation errors!

Comment: Jepp, it's working now:) I needed to rewrite some main structs of the library and change c-files to cpp-files. The original structues would never have been accepted By android studio:(