No implementation found for Int when i use .so file android
I want to use .so file, i've success to load the library but the function is not working. Below is the code
Structure

MainActivity.java

JniLoader.java
package com.example.testapps;

public class JniLoader {

    public JniLoader() {}

    public static boolean LoadLib() {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("MeasureCamara");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("WARNING: Could not load library");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public native int openDevice(); // Declare native methods
    public native int ctrlDevice(int cmd, int arg);
    public native int closeDevice();

}

Gradle

Logcat

I'm stuck for two days, thanks for any helping!

You either don't have a C function matching the proper name or the proper parameters.  Post your JNI interface on the C level.  There needs to be a void java_com_example_testapps_JniLoader_openDevice() spelled exactly that way, and if your library is C++ the function must be declared as extern "C"

the .so file is from another project, so i don't have any access from that. I just try to connect with it with the code above. Or am i need create C function to connect my .so with my java?

After i review yours @GabeSechan and get the another insight from https://stackoverflow.com/a/59577218/17299518, i try changed the package id to same with the .so file. And it's working. Thank You! Maybe this is bad, but currently i don't have any idea about it.

You only need to change the package of the JNILoader class.  But that's a perfectly acceptable solution.
